# EnumSet modifiers inside an enum in Java

Tags: java, enums, redundancy, modifier, enumset

It makes sense declaring an EnumSet within a enum with the modifiers `static` and `final`? Or are redundant?

Example:

```
public enum Guitar {
    STRATOCASTER,
    LES_PAUL,
    CLASSIC;

    private static final EnumSet electrics = EnumSet.of(STRATOCASTER, LES_PAUL);
}
```

Thank you!

Comment: Classes are usually named singular, not plural so your class name should be `Guitar` not `Guitars` by convention. Applies to `enum`s..

Comment: Thank's for your contribution! :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## tl;dr

```
static final public Set ELECTRICS = Set.of( STRATOCASTER , LES_PAUL ) ;
```

## Details

Regarding your code:

> `private static final EnumSet electrics = EnumSet.of(STRATOCASTER, LES_PAUL);`

## <strike>`private`</strike>

As written, no need for `private`.

If marked `private` no other code would have access to this set. So it would serve no purpose.

## `static`

Yes, `static` is appropriate. An enum defines a specific number of named instances of its class. The instantiation happens automatically when the class first loads at runtime. So each enum object is a separate object. No need for each of them to have their own set. The set is unchanging, so just define a single instance of that set by marking it `static`.

This makes the syntax more clear as we do not involve any of the enum objects by name. Example code:

```
Set < Guitar > guitars = Guitar.ELECTRICS ;
```

Or:

```
Guitar.ELECTRICS.stream.forEach( System.out::println ) ;
```

## `final`

Yes, mark it as `final` if this set will be unchanging during the entire run of this app. Marking as `final` prevents any other set from being assigned to that field.

## `EnumSet` ➠ `Set`

Regarding the first `EnumSet`, make that simply `Set`.

Generally better to promise a more general superclass or interface rather than lock yourself into a specific concrete class.

## `electrics` ➠ `ELECTRICS`

The name `electrics` should be in all uppercase, if you intend this set to be fixed, unchanging. Constants in Java are named in all uppercase, by convention. So, `ELECTRICS`.

## Plural naming of collection

Good that you named `ELECTRICS` in plural. This name suggests the fact that is a collection rather than a singular enum object.

## `Set.of` for unmodifiable collection

As for the second `EnumSet`, generally using `EnumSet` is the right choice for handling enum objects. The `EnumSet` class is highly optimized for enums, resulting in very fast performance while using very little memory.

But the problem here is that `EnumSet` is mutable. I expect you do not want any errant code to be adding or removing elements from your set.

So we want an immutable collection there. Java provides an [unmodifiable set](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/util/Set.html#unmodifiable) via the [`Set.of…`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/util/Set.html#of(E,E)) methods.

Under the covers, those methods are free to use any concrete class they want, and so are free to optimize in the choice of underlying class. So you might end up with an efficient concrete class like `EnumSet`. But that is not paramount, as being immuable trumps performance in this situation.

## Solution code

So I would write that code as:

```
static final public Set ELECTRICS = Set.of( STRATOCASTER , LES_PAUL ) ;
```

## Explicitly immutable collections in third-party library

An alternative to using `Set.of` is to add a library to your project that provides immutability as an explicit part of its collection data types. Perhaps [*Eclipse Collections*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Eclipse_(brand)) or [*Google Guava*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Google_Guava).

As for redundancy, see correct [Answer by Live and Let Live](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66053029/642706).

Answer (score 2):

> It makes sense declaring an EnumSet within a enum with the modifiers
> static and final? Or are redundant?

No, they are not redundant. Consider the following example in which `nonElectrics` can be set because it's not `final`.

```
import java.util.EnumSet;

enum Guitar {
    STRATOCASTER, LES_PAUL, CLASSIC;

    private static final EnumSet<Guitar> electrics = EnumSet.of(STRATOCASTER, LES_PAUL);
    static EnumSet<Guitar> nonElectrics = EnumSet.of(CLASSIC);

    public static EnumSet<Guitar> getNonElectrics() {
        return nonElectrics;
    }

    public static void setNonElectrics(EnumSet<Guitar> nonElectrics) {
        Guitar.nonElectrics = nonElectrics;
    }

    public static EnumSet<Guitar> getElectrics() {
        return electrics;
    }

    public boolean isElectronics() {
        return electrics.contains(this);
    }
}

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println(Guitar.STRATOCASTER.isElectronics());
        System.out.println(Guitar.CLASSIC.isElectronics());
        EnumSet<Guitar> electrics = EnumSet.of(Guitar.STRATOCASTER, Guitar.LES_PAUL);
        Guitar.setNonElectrics(electrics);
        System.out.println(Guitar.getNonElectrics());
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

This is not redundant, fields in enum class not static or final.
But, you can't invoke not static enum's fields from other classes.

Comment: But if, like in the example, it is private and there are not setter it couldn't be modified, right?

Comment: Then, if it can't be modified, that final modifier couldn't be unnecessary?

Comment: Each field, which may be final must be final.)